# ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Text (i am using expo application for react native)

Tags: react-native, expo, referenceerror

this error is showing in my ios screen after downloading java script in my device.

```
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Text

This error is located at:
in App (at registerRootComponent.js:35)
in RootErrorBoundary (at registerRootComponent.js:34)
in ExpoRootComponent (at renderApplication.js:33)
in RCTView (at View.js:60)
in View (at AppContainer.js:102)
in RCTView (at View.js:60)
in View (at AppContainer.js:122)
in AppContainer (at renderApplication.js:32)
```

Comment: add code to your question

Answer (score 10):

Import Text from react native.

```
 import {
      View,
      Text,
 } from 'react-native';
```

Answer (score 1):

Importing `react-native` is not enough here.

> Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-native'

Instead, you need an additional package:

```
yarn add react-native-web
```

Now you are able to use

```
import {Text} from 'react-native'
```